# "Failed to download reload update information." using Trigger.IO Realod

Tags: reload, trigger.io

I am having a problem with Reload.
After I push a change, I go to the simulator, press the home button and the console shows me:

```
[   INFO] 2013-07-08 12:49:59.127 Forge[5316:1353] [INFO] Checking for reload update
[   INFO] 2013-07-08 12:50:00.272 Forge[5316:1353] [INFO] reload update available
[   INFO] 2013-07-08 12:50:00.272 Forge[5316:1353] [INFO] Starting Reload update
[   INFO] 2013-07-08 12:50:01.979 Forge[5316:1353] [INFO] Failed to download reload update information.
```

Every time I get this "Failed to download reload update information."

I am trying to push to a stream, and this is my JS code within the app:

```
//Handling Reload Proccess
        //We must comment "testadores" and uncomment "usuariosfinais" when releasing to the Apple Store
        forge.reload.switchStream("testadores", successEmpty, errorEmpty);
        //forge.reload.switchStream("usuariosfinais", successEmpty, errorEmpty);
        forge.reload.updateReady.addListener(upDateReady, errorEmpty);
        function successEmpty(content){}
        function errorEmpty(content){}
        function upDateReady(){
            forge.reload.applyAndRestartApp(goRestartToUpdate, errorEmpty)
        }
        function goRestartToUpdate(){
            alert("Uma nova versão do aplicativo está disponível e será implementada");         
        }
```

Any thoughts?